# UPS on SharePoint 2016, AD LDA and custom generic ldap connector

Tags: 2016, ups, mim, ad-lds

I have set up MIM and it is connected to an AD LDS LDAP server. I need this to connect to SharePoint UPS - I have seen the SharePoint connector but will that get the information from the generic ldap connector ?  I also do not want to use the UPS service account because I don't understand why I need to when I have the users already in MIM ?

Any info would be brilliant.

Comment: May be you can use it or may be you cant .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See there are 2 connectors with MIM , one is the ADMA that connects Active directory(LDAP connector in your case) with the metaverse connector and the metaverse connector then connects with SPMA .

The SPMA connector is the connector linked with the SharePoint user profile service application.

So yes,you need SPMA to sync all the data/attributes etc.. from metaverse to SharePoint.

The other doubt regarding usage of User Profile service account , so i would recommend you to not do it.

Instead create a dedicated service account for MIM and make sure it has required access on User profile databases and central administration .

Let me know if you have more doubts in this one.

Comment: perfect answer, but how do I not use the UPS account ? If I look at the SPMA documentation I have to enter it into the powershell script ?

Comment: Correct so we went through the same thing. what you can do is create a service account in active directory like "mimservice" and in the sync.ps1 script enter that service account . Likewise while installing the MIM you will have to enter this account as well. You will  have to add this account in the administrators group in the server where MIM is being installed and give this account access on User profile service application ,user profile  databases and add this to central admin administrators group.

Comment: excellent, I have a mimservice account - so if I put that in, instead and assign the permissions then happy days ?

Comment: Exactly correct !!!!!!!! You dont want to mess up the user profile if anything goes wrong , hence the need to use a dedicated service account for MIM.

Comment: what would the ForestDNSName then because we are using AD LDS (which gives out the LDAP) ?

Comment: For this you need to run the Get-ADForest powershell command...this is independent of the connector you are using ......

Comment: cool, but the domain where AD LDS comes from is not the local domain as such... we use AD LDS for LDAPCP and ADFS for authentcation. So do I need the dns address of the domain the user accounts stem from ?

Comment: Correct !!!... Since you are using ADFS ,the users and its sync with the metaverse is also going to be established from the ADFS itself . So the forest dns name of the ADFS needs to be provided